# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def binary_search(li, targetValue):
    low, high = 0, len[li] #error on this line
    while low <= high:
        mid = (high - low)/2
        if li[mid] == targetValue:
             return "we found it!"
        elif li[mid] > targetValue:
             low = mid - 1;
        elif li[mid] < targetValue:
             high = mid + 1;
    print "search failure "
```

just posted this question recently, but my code still doesn't work?

Comment: You can't write `len[li]` when `len()` is a built-in function to compute the length of an object.

Answer (score 11):

you are using the wrong brackets `len(li)` not `len[li]`

Remember when you are trying to access a function you need to use `function(args)` if you use `[]` you are actually accessing a sequence like a list. `your_list[index]`. len is a built in function so you need the `()`

Answer (score 5):

`len` is a built-in function, but you are trying to use it as a sequence:

```
len[li]
```

*Call* the function instead:

```
len(li)
```

Note the shape change there, indexing is done with square brackets, calling is done with round parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Python uses `(...)` to call a function and `[...]` to index a collection.  Furthermore, what you are trying to do now is index the built-in function `len`.

To fix the problem, use parenthesis instead of square brackets:

```
low, high = 0, len(li)
```

Comment: it still doesn't work for some reason..it doesn't give me an error anymore, but it just doesn't output anything

Comment: @user2928929 - How are you calling `binary_search`?  Are you using `print` like you should as in `print binary_search(li, targetValue)`?

Comment: yup, even if I say print binary_search(li, targetValue) , if the targetValue is in the list, it returns "we found it" but if it isn't it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

It took me couple of minute to figure out what is the mistake.
Sometimes a blindspot stops you from looking at obvious.

Incorrect

```
msg = "".join['Temperature out of range. Range is between', str(
            HeatedRefrigeratedShippingContainer.MIN_CELSIUS), " and ", str(
            RefrigeratorShippingContainer.MAX_CELSIUS)]
```

Correct

```
msg = "".join(['Temperature out of range. Range is between', str(
        HeatedRefrigeratedShippingContainer.MIN_CELSIUS), " and ", str(
        RefrigeratorShippingContainer.MAX_CELSIUS)])
```

As you can see join is a method and has to be called with () which was missing and causing the issue. Hope it helps all to look for the method and add ().